# Sending a JSON object to an ASP.NET webservice in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json, extjs

I am trying to use an ajax proxy to send JSON parameters to a ASP.NET webservice but unfortunately I am just not able to make it work. I have managed to get the desired results by using an Ajax request (see end of this post), but not when loading the Store.

I have tried various solutions I found on the internet, but none of them worked for me and I am not able to find out what it is I am doing wrong. Firebug either tells me I am not sending a JSON object or there are not child objects for my JSON object (depending on which solution I am currently trying).

**Store**

```
var resourceStore = new Sch.data.ResourceStore({
        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : 'http://80.146.239.188/SmartWeb/Utility/SmartourHandler.ashx',
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
            actionMethods: {
                read: 'POST'
            },
            noCache: false,
            reader : {
                type : 'json',
                root : 'result.vehicleInfos'
            },
            pageParam: undefined,
            startParam: undefined,
        },
        model : 'MyResource',
        autoLoad:false,
});
```

**Loading the store**

```
this.scheduler.getResourceStore().load({params: Ext.JSON.encode({
        id: '1',
        method: 'getToursByDate',
        params: {startDate: '20120704', endDate: '20120704'},
    })
});
```

Oh and I guess this may help, the following ajax request gives me the desired result, so if anyone could tell me how to get the same result via the ajax proxy of the store i would be a very happy man.

**Ajax request**

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    params: Ext.JSON.encode({
        id: '1',
        method: 'getToursByDate',
        params: {startDate: '20120704', endDate: '20120704'},
    }),
    url: 'http://80.146.239.188/SmartWeb/Utility/SmartourHandler.ashx'
});
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: How is it not working? Your server sends HTTP 200?

Comment: Yes, I get HTTP 200. The problem is, that the JSON data I want to send to the webservice is not included in the POST, but when I use the Ajax request it is included and I get a correct answer.